# Error when not root: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Tags: docker

Why am I getting this message?

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

I dont get this message if im running as root, though

```
[root@mymachine redisc]# whoami
root
[root@mymachine redisc]# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
[root@mymachine redisc]# sudo su myuser
[myuserp@mymachine redisc]$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

how can I run dockerd so that all users can access it (not just root)?

Comment: Add the users who should have access to the `docker` group (presumably; details depend on your OS's packaging, and you haven't told us which OS that is). You *really* don't want untrusted accounts like `nobody` to have access, so providing universal access to all accounts on the system is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Look at Docker post-installation steps - Manage Docker as a non-root user https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Comment: @gile thank you that worked

Comment: As this is a configuration-and-deployment question, as opposed to a development question, if there's intent to keep it open on a StackExchange site, it should probably migrate to ServerFault.